# Mock axios and kitsu with jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm creating some tests and I'm using Kitsu (https://github.com/wopian/kitsu/tree/master/packages/kitsu) as a cliente to consume APIs.

I need to mock the API requests but I can't. Kitsu uses axios inside and I don't know how to mock the structure:

```
Kitsu {
  camel: [Function: index],
  resCase: [Function: index$1],
  plural: [Function: pluralize] {
    plural: [Function],
    isPlural: [Function],
    singular: [Function],
    isSingular: [Function],
    addPluralRule: [Function],
    addSingularRule: [Function],
    addUncountableRule: [Function],
    addIrregularRule: [Function]
  },
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/vnd.api+json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.api+json'
  },
  axios: [Function: wrap] {
    request: [Function: wrap],
    getUri: [Function: wrap],
    delete: [Function: wrap],
    get: [Function: wrap],
```

I need to mock get method inside axios property.
How can I do that using jest ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `axios-mock-adapter` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-mock-adapter)

e.g.

```
const axios = require('axios');
const MockAdapter = require('axios-mock-adapter');
const mock = new MockAdapter(axios);

mock.onGet('http://somehost/path').reply(200, 'response goes here');
```

Comment: using this code, Kitsu still making the API request. Kitsu is not being mocked.

Comment: Make sure you're mocking the whole URI properly? I'm doing it this way in tests in some of my own projects. The main problem I ran into was when I didn't have the URI correct when setting up the mock.

Comment: yes, as I said, Kitsu has a get method. This get method is being called and not get method from axios.

Comment: Kitsu itself uses axios-mock-adapter for its tests. https://github.com/wopian/kitsu/blob/master/packages/kitsu/src/get.spec.js

I can't help you without more details. Post some example code?